# How to insert ($x-$y) inside a bash printed string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, sh

I have this simple problem but I am very unfamiliar with bash syntax;
I need to print this line that should output something like `Starting 3 more instances`:

```
echo 'Starting '($2 - $total_running_instances)' more instances'
```

But I don't know how bash expects me to link that x - y calculation to the rest of the string, I tried putting "+" between them or "." like PHP handles string, I get syntax errors if I try that way:

```
echo 'Starting '.($2 - $total_running_instances).' more instances'

echo 'Starting '+($2 - $total_running_instances)+' more instances'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation for arithmetic expansion (evaluating an arithmetic expression and expanding to its result) is `$((...))`. You can write:

```
echo "Starting $(($2 - total_running_instances)) more instances"
```

See [§3.5.5 "Arithmetic Expansion" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion).

The problem you're seeing is that `(...)` is *not* a notation for arithmetic expansion, but rather, a notation for running a whole Bash command in a [subshell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Execution-Environment).

Answer (score 0):

Alternately:

```
echo "Starting `expr $2 - $total_running_instances` more instances"
```

Comment: There's no need to use `expr` for arithmetic in `bash` or any other POSIX-compatible shell.